# Update all column formulas when inserting a row

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've been looking for a way to update all of my formulas when I add a row to my spread sheet.

Say I have =AVERAGEIFS($G2:$G6, $G2:$G6, ">0", $D2:$D6, "Resell") on a column and then I add a new row above or below, that formula stays G2 G6, etc, I need it to go from G2 to G7. Is there an easy way to update all formulas or have this done automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Given your example formula, what is going on below Row 6 before adding a row? (It is always most efficient and effective if you allow us to see your sheet by sharing a link.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending (as @Erik Tyler says) what is below row 6, you may be able to use full column references (omitting just the first row which might be a header):

```
=AVERAGEIFS($G2:$G, $G2:$G, ">0", $D2:$D, "Resell")
```

I have left the dollar signs in assuming you might want to copy the formula across at some stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a row before or after a range, it doesn't expand the range.  However, if you insert a row within the defined range, it will adjust the cell references.

Without seeing your data, here are some kludgy solutions that I have used in the past:

1. Insert a blank row at the top of your data, then hide it.  Use this as the start of your range, when someone adds a row to the top of the data set, it is still inside the range, and your formula will update the range.
2. If you are the only one using it, only insert in the middle of the range and sort as necessary.